# heart rate query returns empty set

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Trying to access my heartRate data from google fit using the History api.
The sign in and permissions are executed correctly.
But the query is the real issue here.
The Data point values always seem to return empty.

```
public void setFitnessOption() {
                fitnessOptions =
                        FitnessOptions.builder()
                                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                                .build();
              }



public void requestGoogleFitPermission() {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS },
                        GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);

                GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
                GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                        account,
                        fitnessOptions);
              }

private Task<DataReadResponse> readHRHistoryData() {

                DataReadRequest readRequest = queryHRFitnessData();
                return Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                        .readData(readRequest)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(
                                new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
                                        Log.v(TAG, "Success" + dataReadResponse);
                                        printData(dataReadResponse);
                                    }
                                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.v(TAG, "Failture");
                                    }
                                });
            }


public static DataReadRequest queryHRFitnessData() {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date now = new Date();
                cal1.setTime(now);
                long endTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();

                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

                DataReadRequest readRequest =
                        new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
                                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                                .build();

                return readRequest;
            }


public static void printData(DataReadResponse dataReadResult) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
                        if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
                            for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
                                List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                                Log.v(TAG, "Datasets: " + dataSets);
                                for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                                    dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
                            System.out.print("Number of returned DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
                            for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
                                dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                            }
                        }
                    }


private static void dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Name: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
                Log.v(TAG, "Fields: " + dataSet.getDataSource().getDataType().getFields());

                Log.v(TAG, "Data Point Values :" + dataSet.getDataPoints());
                for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Data Point:");
                    Log.v(TAG, "Type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
                    Log.v(TAG, "Start: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    Log.v(TAG, "End: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
                    for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Field: " + field.getName() + ", Value : " + dp.getValue(field).asFloat());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Log:

```
V/nativehealth: Successcom.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataReadResponse@61ae9a7
    Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: 1
    Datasets: [DataSet{d:heart_rate.summary:gms:aggregated []}]
    Name: com.google.heart_rate.summary
V/nativehealth: Fields: [average(f), max(f), min(f)]
    Data Point Values :[]
```

I have maintained heart rate data on my google fit app. Yet my code returns empty set.
What am I missing out here??

**Update:**
I tried to insert data (HeartRate = 81) using HistoryClient and then I tried to read this data. It worked perfectly fine.

Log:

```
Datasets: [DataSet{d:heart_rate.summary:gms:aggregated [RawDataPoint{[81.0, 81.0, 81.0]@[1612494973714000000, 1612494973714000000](0,1)}]}]
    Name: com.google.heart_rate.summary
V/nativehealth: Fields: [average(f), max(f), min(f)]
    Data Point Values :[DataPoint{[81.0, 81.0, 81.0]@[1612494973714000000, 1612494973714000000,raw=0](d:heart_rate.summary:gms:aggregated r:heart_rate.bpm:com.nativehealth:)}]
    Data Point:
    Type: com.google.heart_rate.summary
V/nativehealth: Start: 11:16:13 AM
V/nativehealth: End: 11:16:13 AM
    Field: average, Value : 81.0
    Field: max, Value : 81.0
    Field: min, Value : 81.0
```

But I couldn't see this data in my google fit app!!! This entire process is so confusing. Anyone PLEASE HELP!

Comment: This means you're dead.

Comment: wow. alright mate.